# Consume SSL Secured APIs in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, https, cryptography

We have an application that has two projects as follows (1) AppClient – This dotnet core MVC project and it is running on **WebServer** on IIS (2) AppService – this is dotnet core WebAPI project. It runs on **AppServer** on IIS.

Only AppClient can consume APIs exposed by AppService. These APIs are hosted over HTTP. Currently both applications are over the same network. We have a requirement to secure REST APIs by using HTTPS.
I have a few questions:

1. If WebAPIs are hosted over HTTPS using SSL, what code changes will I have to do on AppClient?
   Will I have to write a cryptography layer in order to every time send encrypted requests to AppService or IIS will take care of it? If so, how and where I am supposed to maintain the public keys served by AppService.
2. Do I have to make any code change in AppService to host it over HTTPS or binding it with SSL in IIS is all that I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To consume APIs hosted on HTTPS, an instance of HttpClientHandler needs to be created and then it should be passed as an argument to HttpClient. See the code below

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None && cert.GetCertHashString().ToLower() == "certificateThumbPrint")
    {
        return true;   //Is valid
    }
    return false;
};

client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("...");
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(...);
```